# Using MS Access to obtain data across linked tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to MS Access and am trying to speed up a data gathering process that is taking forever in Powershell. In Powershell I have 10 or so web API calls to get data and each comes back as an object with multiple properties (fields.) Each set of data has related fields to 1 or more of the other sets of data. Getting the data is very quick but piping an array of objects to where-object to select-object takes over an hour and there's really not that much data. Each object contains 500-1500 "records" and 5 to 10 "fields" so I thought why not export that data and use something that's intended to search through data to do the job?  I exported each object as a separate .CSV file. So enter MS Access..

I imported each of the CSV's as a separate table (easy enough.) I'm going to simplify this down for this example to the following 3 tables:

[Tables]https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCH1F.jpg

Every table has fields that relate it over to other tables. Pretty much there's some sort of Id field in every table that is related to another Id field in a different table that I need to pull a field called "name" from.  I'm trying to follow the bread crumbs from the Player name to it's Network name to it's Application name, to it's Layout name, etc... I want to build a query that I would eventually just be able to export as an Excel file. I also would prefer to just write out the SQL unless it's really easier to to understand the visual query builder. I'm looking to build a sheet with the following information:

Player's Name would include all names from the Players table and getting just that data makes sense to me. SELECT Name AS PlayerName FROM Players   Everything else, not so much. I feel like this will end up being some mega query as I get deeper into related table after related table. In Excel, it would be straightforward using Vlookups across tabs but that doesn't seem to be the best approach. Given the info above, I'm trying to achieve the following output:

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhmE8.jpg)

Any help with strategy and syntax greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) clause.

```
SELECT
  Players.Name PlayerName, Networks.Name PlayerNetwork, Applications.Name ApplicationName
FROM
  Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Networks
ON
  Networks.ID = Players.NetworkId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Applications
ON
  Applications.Id = Players.ApplicationID
```

Comment: I had to modify the syntax a little but this is certainly the right answer. I appreciate the help and now I need to research joins to fully understand them. Thanks!  My slightly modified syntax that worked in MS Access case anyone else needs it:SELECT
Players.Name as PlayerName, Networks.Name as NetworkName, Applications.Name as PlayerApplication
FROM
((Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Networks
ON Networks.Id = Players.NetworkId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Applications
ON Players.ApplicationId = Applications.Id)